# Android-FirebaseAuth-TwitterLogin returns error 403 Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, twitter-login

I'm trying to add authenticate using Twitter on my Android App using Firebase-Auth
I followed the documentation from Firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/twitter-login

And set the OAuth redirect URI (my-app-xxxx.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler) on Twitter app's settings page.

When call

```
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        .startActivityForSignInWithProvider( /* activity= */requireActivity(), provider.build())
```

it opens the browser and shows the error
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests from this Android client application  are blocked"}}
[image: Please check the image that shows the error]

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @yoonhok Actually I removed the Twitter login from my App.